# Is there a way to group plots based on matching row values?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-analysis

I have a data frame like shown below.

```
Country      Type            2011       2012       2013
Afghanistan Estimate         -1.63      -1.57     -1.41
Afghanistan Sources           5           8         7
Afghanistan Percentile       0.95       0.94       2.36
.
.
.
Zambia      Estimate         1.63       1.57      1.41
Zambia      Sources           7           10        8
Zambia      Percentile       0.88       0.77       1.54
```

I am hoping to generate plots (preferably line graphs) for each country (`Type` will be used as legend). Is there a way to group plots for each country? I am relatively new and don't know where to begin.

Comment: By grouping, do you mean for each Country you have one subplot with multiple graphs (based on type) or that for each row you have a plot but you want these plots to appear 'close' to each other on some kind of grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't get away with at least some transformations.
If it's OK to use [Seaborn](http://seaborn.pydata.org/index.html) for plotting, it could look something like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from io import StringIO

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO('''
Country,Type,2011,2012,2013
Afghanistan,Estimate,-1.63,-1.57,-1.41
Afghanistan,Sources,5,8,7
Afghanistan,Percentile,0.95,0.94,2.36
Zambia,Estimate,1.63,1.57,1.41
Zambia,Sources,7,10,8
Zambia,Percentile,0.88,0.77,1.54
'''), dtype={'Country' : 'string',
             'Type' : 'string',
             '2011' : 'float',
             '2012' : 'float',
             '2013' : 'float'})

#        Country        Type  2011   2012  2013
# 0  Afghanistan    Estimate -1.63  -1.57 -1.41
# 1  Afghanistan     Sources  5.00   8.00  7.00
# 2  Afghanistan  Percentile  0.95   0.94  2.36
# 3       Zambia    Estimate  1.63   1.57  1.41
# 4       Zambia     Sources  7.00  10.00  8.00
# 5       Zambia  Percentile  0.88   0.77  1.54

# transform to long format
df = df.melt(id_vars=['Country', 'Type'], 
             value_vars=['2011','2012','2013'], 
             var_name='Year')

# df after melt:
#         Country        Type  Year  value
# 0   Afghanistan    Estimate  2011  -1.63
# 1   Afghanistan     Sources  2011   5.00
# 2   Afghanistan  Percentile  2011   0.95
# 3        Zambia    Estimate  2011   1.63
# 4        Zambia     Sources  2011   7.00
# 5        Zambia  Percentile  2011   0.88
# 6   Afghanistan    Estimate  2012  -1.57
# 7   Afghanistan     Sources  2012   8.00
# 8   Afghanistan  Percentile  2012   0.94
# 9        Zambia    Estimate  2012   1.57
# 10       Zambia     Sources  2012  10.00
# 11       Zambia  Percentile  2012   0.77
# 12  Afghanistan    Estimate  2013  -1.41
# 13  Afghanistan     Sources  2013   7.00
# 14  Afghanistan  Percentile  2013   2.36
# 15       Zambia    Estimate  2013   1.41
# 16       Zambia     Sources  2013   8.00
# 17       Zambia  Percentile  2013   1.54

sns.relplot(data=df, kind='line', x='Year', 
            y='value', hue='Type', col="Country")
```

[image]